# QlikView - Sybase data encoding

Tags: encoding, sybase, qlikview

I am loading data into QlikView report from different sources, one of them is Sybase db. Seems like Sybase db is using ISO 8859-1 encoding, but there are also Russian characters there, and QlikView just don't display them properly.

I don't see the way to manually define encoding in Qlikview. Is there any?

I tried to specify cyrillic charset in ODBC settings, but it also doesn't help. Funny thing is ASE isql (tool to run queries on Sybase) there is no issue with encoding. Can I specify encoding when select stuff in Sybase?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a charset conversion issue. My guess is that your isql has a charset conversion option enabled, but your qlikview session has not.

Comment: This might be true. What I need than is how to enable this option for QV

Comment: That's more of a Qlikview issue